# How to obtain from sys/devices the device path with libudev in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, udev

I have included libudev in my Linux project and want to print something to the correct printer. I have 2 different printers connected. However, sometimes they change from lp0 to lp1 or lp2.

```
path = /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1
serial=Sewoo_POS_PRINTER vendor=Sewoo device=1-1 node=/dev/bus/usb/001/021 devnum=21, busnum=1
```

How to get the udev address in C/C++ for these? I want to get following:

```
/dev/usb/lp0
```

Which commands can do this? I don't want to call system("...").

Comment: Maybe you need to start to look at libusb: https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417618/get-device-path-based-on-usb-vidpid-in-linux

Comment: Thanks for directions. My first attempt now will be based on : https://github.com/Malanche/escpospp/blob/master/src/Printer.cpp